# Cannot find/create new file in Docker

Tags: python, docker, type-conversion

I couldn't find any information or a way to do this, and as I am new to Docker, I thought here would be a good place to ask.

I have python code, where I take a .jpg image file, convert it to base64, then decode the base64 and create a .png image file with that data. It's been working outside of Docker. Here's the basics of the code:

```
import base64
from PIL import Image

with open("testImg.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

decoded_string = base64.b64decode(encoded_string)

newImg = open("newImg.png", "w+")
newImg.write(str(decoded_string))
image_file.close()
newImg.close()

Image.open('newImg.png').show()
```

this creates a new png image and even opens it for me. When I run it in Docker, everything works great, but the file won't open, nor does it seem to be created, because it's not located in the project folder.

The `Image.open()` part is the least of my worries, I assume it's not opening because its being run inside of Docker or something of the sort.

My real question is, where is the `newImg.png` file?

if you'd like to see my Dockerfile or code

`$ docker pull chriscrutt/heyyo`

Comment: could you run `docker exec -it <container_name> bash` and find out the file?

Comment: ok I created a container from the image and ran it using `docker start -a -I <container_name>`, then doing `ls` and running `python app.py` (the code above in my question) it created the new .png file, which I could see by doing `ls`. How do I access it outside of docker/its container though?

Comment: to access files into docker's container you can use `volumes`. Add `VOLUME <path_where_placed_generated_files>` in your `Dockerfile`. When you run container you need to mount this volume to your local filesystem.